# Create Lead with Salesforce API

Tags: salesforce

I have a lot of simple HTML web forms. The forms take a user's information, which should map to a bunch of fields in Salesforce.

I've been using Eloqua to do this migration to Salesforce, but I'm not too happy with Eloqua and am looking into injecting the data directly into Salesforce in lieu of using Eloqua.

There's a plethora of resources on this topic, and honestly it's kind of daunting.

I'm really just looking to make a simple C# or Javascript call into our company's Salesforce instance, take the fields from my HTML form, and put them on the Lead or Contact in Salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only wanted to insert Leads, then the Salesforce [Web-to-Lead](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_web-to-lead.htm) functionality is straight forward to implement. You can basically drop the generated form into you HTML page. It does have a number of limitations, particularly around [preventing spam](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23705/can-web-to-lead-be-protected-from-spammers-without-additional-server-side-proces).

For C#, I'd recommend going with the Partner API. You could use the Enterprise API, which is tailored to your specific org, but the Partner API will serve you well in just about any scenario.

There is example C# code for a [create call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sample_create_call.htm) and [update call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sample_update_call.htm). When combined with the [Examples Using the Partner WSDL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_partner_examples.htm) you will have most of what you need to insert or update Leads and Contacts.

Incidentally, the [Salesforce StackExchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.